# how can i inject a service into an entity repository Symfony2 doctrine?

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony, doctrine-orm

how can i inject a service into an entity repository with the dependency injection?

i try like this:

```
<service id="rp.repository.user" class="RP\CoreBundle\Repository\UserRepository" 
factory-service="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" factory-method="getRepository">
  <call method="setSecurityContext">
    <argument type="service" id="security.context"/>
  </call>
</service>
```

but the setSecurityContext it's never called
Plz help

Comment: i don't know if what i want to do it's a good thing or not.  i want to access to the security context into the repository to check if the current user have the role_user or not to add some filter in all dql request. with the DI i thing it's not possible because the entity manager call the getRepository function and instantiate the requested repository, doesn't get it from the container, someone have an idea for this problem? thx a lot

Answer (score 8):

Injecting a service into a repository isn't recommended, since it breaks Separation of Concerns. Instead, you should use a service class that calls the repository. Based on your comment, a simple work flow would look like this:

- Define `UserService` class, and register it as a service.
- Inject `security.context` into `UserService`
- Define `UserService::getUsers()` (or whatever you want the method to be). It's here in the method that you would use `security.context` to set criteria for the query. You could either pass the criteria directly to your `UserRepository::getUsers()` method, or build the DQL in the `UserService` object and pass it to `UserRepository`.
- `UserService::getUsers()` returns whatever `UserRepository::getUsers()` returns.

This is how I like to handle situations like these, but for the sake of completeness, you could also use simple setter injection on your repository. You would fetch the repository through the entity manager (and not from the service container as in your question), and simply call `$userRepository->setSecurityContext($this->get('security.context'))`.

Comment: and propably an exception if it is required ?